# Alternative to zc.buildout that runs on Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, virtualenv, buildout

My project uses buildout to do primarily two things: automatically fetch dependencies and create scripts; and setup cron jobs (on deployment machines) using the usercrontab buildout recipe.

But buildout is not yet available for Python 3.

So I would like to consider alternatives for buildout. I know that both virtualenv and pip work on Python 3 - but what is the preferred tool to *automate* the build toolchain (of creating virtualenv, and automatically installing/upgrading deps)? There is fabric, paver, and so on. What is your preferred tool of choice in this case? It must work seamlessly on both Windows and *nix.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what results from passing buildout through `2to3`?

Comment: There isn't any alternative, as the lack of answers suggest. However, we are working on it. :) zc.buildout is a hard one.

Comment: You mention fabric, paver, and "so on"; have you considered puppet or chef, too?  For your specific requirements, is there a particular need for it to be a Python solution?

Comment: I've settled for Fabric - https://github.com/srid/fablib

Comment: @Sridhar Ratnakumar: You should add that as an answer so this doesn't show up on the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote my own toolset on top of Fabric that does the core of what zc.buildout does. See https://github.com/srid/fablib

Answer (score 3):

[Buildout 2 is in alpha](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/zc.buildout/2.0.0a1) at the time of this writing.  It supports Python 3.